# How to mount NTFS file system Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: mount

I have been able to access all of the partitions on my disks.  One day, after trying to download a file, one partition won't mount.  They are NTFS.  I took the disk out and put it on a windows system and it had no problem (except one folder I could not delete).  I opened the "disks" utility and it says there is no problem with it, but it can't mount it either.

Comment: Did you run chkdsk and perhaps defrag in Windows? NTFS requires maintenance that you can only do from Windows. If not dual booting, best to have Windows repair disk or better not use NTFS. Also make sure mounting in Windows does not have hibernation flag set as Windows 8 or 10 defaults to fast start up which sets hibernation flag on all NTFS partitions. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: I did run chkdsk on windows.  This computer was dual booting (XP), but I got a new motherboard/cpu and it will have nothing to do with XP.  I even tried re-installing it from the original disk and it just crashes.    That is why I still have some NTFS partitions.  I ran chkdsk on win 7 and did it for the other partitions as well, and this is the only one that doesn't mount.

Comment: @PSimdars What is the *exact error message* it gives you when you attempt to mount it?

Comment: I had XP dual booted until 2011 when I got a new tiny SSD and SSD need AHCI to be able to use trim. But XP only worked in IDE mode, not AHCI. So XP was retired. Also chkdsk from Windows 7 converts PBR - partition boot sector for NTFS to have bootmgr in it, and with XP type NTFS it has ntldr in it. You have to run chkdsk from XP to fix that. But running chkdsk from Windows 7 can fix errors that chkdsk from XP cannot see. Best to retire both XP & Windows 7 anyway.

Comment: Thomas, I tried from the file manager and it says it is unable to access location.